# Error(1, -4) in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to play the Video and Audio files using Intent. the Media files are placed in the package location(file:///data/data/....).

To PlayVideo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");        
this.startActivity(i);
```

To PlayAudio:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/mp3");
this.startActivity(i);
```

But getting the error as "**Error(1,-4)**". How to clear this?

Comment: The video is in the application package?

Comment: yes Filipe. that is app package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your video file has the `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission so media player can access 
it

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE

You could try playing the video and audio using intent like this:

```
File videoFile2Play = new File("pathtofile");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile2Play), "video/*");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: yes i have created the file with mode_world_readable permission

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem. stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask